# How to use addKeyListener after removeKeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, paint, keylistener

How to `addKeyListener` to a `JPanel` after `removeKeyListener`?

As a matter of fact, in a 2-player game and after one side wins : 
I do not want to continue the game.

So I remove the `keylistener`.

I want to restart the game.

Here I need the `keyListener` again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you friends.
I use a variable named **winType**. It's default value is **0**. If the win condition occurs, I set it to a **positive** value.
So,

> instead of removing keylistener

, I keep the keylisener but it works

> only when winType = 0

When the user clicks on New, I reset winType to 0.

It solved the issue with not repainting after removing keylistener. [Issue Solved]

Answer (score 1):

You can write your KeyListener in a seperate class:

```
public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    // implement needed methods here
}
```

Then you can create your KeyListener by:

```
MyKeyListener keyListener = new MyKeyListener();
addKeyListener(keyListener);
```

And you can remove and add it afterwards again by writing:

```
removeKeyListener(keyListener);
keyListener = new MyKeyListener();
addKeyListener(keyListener);
```